# CSS for Responsive Thumbnails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Rails, Bootstrap and Imagemagick for my app.

I have a thumbnail grid where the images uploaded are of different aspect ratios. See demo site at [mktdemo.herokuapp.com](http://mktdemo.herokuapp.com). Images are resized to thumbnails by imagemagick to fit within a 200x200 space.

I wrote the css below so the thumbnails align consistently. Note that product name is aligned on all products though product imgs are of different aspect ratios. I'm happy with this output.

The problem is that since I'm using fixed pixel sizes, these are not responsive. How do I convert my css into %'s so they resize accordingly?

here is my html.erb

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="row">
     <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
           <div class="thumbnail" > 
             <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive aspect"), listing %>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3><%= listing.name %></h3>
               <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
     <% end %>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
   width: 260px;
   height: 290px;
 }

.thumbnail > img {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
 }


.caption {
   width: 240px;
   height: 90px;
   position: absolute; bottom: 5px; 

  h3 {
     font-size: 17px;
     margin: 2px;
      }

  p {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**
When I remove the thumbnail css above and the first 3 lines of the caption css, this is what happens - the product titles align with the image so are inconsistent. This is what I'm trying to fix.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this **Meta Tag:** in ur `.aspx` page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Refer this : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

Comment: I have this. the reason i needed the css I posted is because my image sizes are of different aspect ratios. So the thumbnails don't align right without the css code.

Answer (score 0):

instead of defining width/height for `thumbnail`..you can remove those definitions as you are already putting them in `<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">`.It means that irrespective of the image width/height...your `grid` will appear aligned and uniform.Moreover you are using `img-responsive` which well handle the responsiveness ONLY if your remove the height/width.Try removing it and change the browser height/width..it will work for sure.

----------------updated answer------------------------
**even after removing you are unable to get the uniformity,so i have a solution where i wrap the individual divs into `li` with a some style,where they align uniformly even for irregular images of width/height.try this**

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="row">
    ###added ul
     <ul style="list-style="none";>
     <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
       ##the li with float:left will remove all extra space caused by irregular images and 
       ##pull every image to left of screen hence aligning them good 
         <li style="float:left !important;width:auto;">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
           <div class="thumbnail" > 
             <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive aspect"), listing %>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3><%= listing.name %></h3>
               <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></p>
            </div>
           </li>
          </div>
       </div>
     <% end %>
    <ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, images are responsive when I remove the thumbnail css but since my images are of different aspect ratios, product titles don't align. i.e. shorter images will have the product title aligned higher than in images with taller heights.

Comment: use `li` to remove extra spacee..i have updated my answer @Moosa ...try it

Comment: Width and float is not the issue. Images align fine on width. Height is the issue. The caption needs to align consistently with a fixed height. See edited post.

Comment: @Moosa how did you solved the issue because i got this bug.

Comment: @pari see my response at the bottom here: it's not a css issue. imagemagick upload snippet needed to some options set. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649334/rails-4-imagemagick-resize-to-fill-space/25658477#25658477